# Editing multiple entities simultaneously

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller, twig

I know how to edit data in one entity, but I need to edit more entities on single page, with single submit button. What is the best option to do it? For being more specific: I've got a Shopping Cart listed, and I want to edit "quantity" fields for each row (cart entity) simultaneously

I know that I have to generate form somehow, and I understand how to do it if I would have "Update" button for every single row, but It must look like on the screenshot given.

[image: Front Screen].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Symfony's [Form Collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). The Form Collection allows you to add and/or edit multiple entities at once. Have a look at the `Tags` examle in the documentation which shows how you can `add/update/delete` tags. You will need to do pretty much the same thing for your shopping cart.

Comment: i think that's it (tested on side-project), but I will find out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

use formType Field for exemple :

suppose you want to mix two entities client which has a relation with an other entity MixedEntity   then  you can do  the following

```
$builder->add('clientName',TextType::class,array(
        'label'=> false
    ))

       .....
       .....

        ->add('anOtherField',TextType::class,array(
        'label'=> false))
        ->add('MixedEntity', new MixedEntityType(),array(
        ));
```

you can set  `cascade={"persist"}` in your entity relation

in twig :

```
{{ form_row(form.MixedEntity.field, { 'attr': {'class': 'CssClass'} }) }}
```

symfony  documentation: 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html

Comment: Consider updating your answer with a few more details explaining how it relates to the question.  Right now it looks like you copied/pasted a few lines from the docs.  It is not clear how it helps with "editing multiple entities" on one page.