# Illegal characters in $child param of FormBuilderInterface->add() method

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I am trying to create a form that will change the user roles, for a lot of users on one page.
Users have unique email and id. However, when I try to add the $child parameter to the form that contains the user's email:

```
$form->add($user->getEmail(), ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $options,
                'placeholder' => 'Select role',
                'data' => $defaultValue,
            ]);
```

...I get an error:

```
The name "mail@example.com" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").
```

This problem disappears if I add a username instead of an email:

```
$form->add($user->getUsername(), ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $options,
                'placeholder' => 'Select role',
                'data' => $defaultValue,
            ]);
```

...but the same usernames can be a great many.

How can I pass a user's email or user id to the form to make sure that the value of the selected role is relevant to a particular user?

Comment: This is not how you do it. You need to use a CollectionType https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010050/8411841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I passed the user id value to the $child parameter, and replaced it in the client side using the "label" option.

```
$form->add($user->getId(), ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $options,
                'placeholder' => 'Select role',
                'data' => $defaultValue,
                'label' => $user->getEmail(),
            ]);
```

So I have a beautiful returned array that looks like:

```
['1' => 'role1',
 '2' => 'role2',
 '3' => 'role3',]
```

However, on the client side everything remains clear, since the ids have been replaced by the users' emails.

Answer (score 0):

the first argument of `FormBuilder::add` is essentially *just a name*, but that name has to conform to some restrictions, specifically, that it doesn't contain special chars (including underscores). It usually also serves as the field name of the entity that is being edited/set/...

in your case, I don't see a reasons for this particular field name (an email address). Have you tried just `'email'`  instead?

```
$form->add('email', ChoiceType::class,
     //...
);
```

I assume(d) that you want one field to select an email. Otherwise, use CollectionType forms, as Vyctorya suggested in a comment.